# Pass hidden value in webpage using jqGrid javascript to server code on record insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to insert a new record in the jqGrid with a default field (hidden) as a parameter to the controller. I was able to pass the parameter for the grid get query request by using

```
datatype: 'json',
postData: {
        parameter_to_pass: function () { return document.getElementById('the_hidden_field').value; }
    },
```

but I can't get the create new record to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should post code which shows **how** you create new record. Do you use form editing, inline editing? How you use it (`formatter: "actions"`, `inlineNav`, `navGrid`, direct call of `addRow` or `editGridRow` etc.)? jqGrid allows you too many possibilities to create new row and the answer on your question depends from the way you chosen.

Comment: oh. sorry. I'm using server side code to add the new record. C# and MVC / EF with the DbSet<>Add entity. I can add a static variable to the parameter in the C# code which works fine, but the problem is I can't figure out how to send it to the server code from the javascript after the grid is loaded. I will post the code.                            Edit: I'm using navGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use form editing the you can extend the data, which will be send during Add operation, by usage of `onclickSubmit` callback:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {},
    {}, // edit options
    { // add options
        onclickSubmit: function () {
            return {
                parameter_to_pass: $("#the_hidden_field").val()
            };
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, not much to go on.  Can you try breaking it up a bit, see where the problem is coming in?  Try setting a variable to the contents of the hidden field and see if you can get the text out of the page for starters.  You could also view the source to check that the hidden field is holding the value you think it is.

```
var hf = document.getElementById('the_hidden_field');
var hfvalue = hf.value;
```